# Is there a way I can remove the margin created between flex elements?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm trying to modify/remove this violet margin.

Also, is there a way I can specify how many items to I want in a certain row using css?
For example, when 1500px, instead of having 3 items and then 1 item, I want 3 items and then another 3 items.

Thank you.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcK3i.jpg

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Georgia;
}

.row {
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.items {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 290px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 2px auto 14px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(120, 17, 25, .7);
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

.item {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000;
  margin: 0px auto 30px auto;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 330px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .search form {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .search input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .search select {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="items">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" />
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <h3>$101</h3>
          <div class="buy_buttons">
            <button class="b_buy">Comprar</button>
            <button class="b_vista">Vista</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/2.jpg" />
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <h3>$101</h3>
          <div class="buy_buttons">
            <button class="b_buy">Comprar</button>
            <button class="b_vista">Vista</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/3.png" />
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <h3>$101</h3>
          <div class="buy_buttons">
            <button class="b_buy">Comprar</button>
            <button class="b_vista">Vista</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/2.jpg" />
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <h3>$101</h3>
          <div class="buy_buttons">
            <button class="b_buy">Comprar</button>
            <button class="b_vista">Vista</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" />
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <h3>$101</h3>
          <div class="buy_buttons">
            <button class="b_buy">Comprar</button>
            <button class="b_vista">Vista</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/2.jpg" />
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <h3>$101</h3>
          <div class="buy_buttons">
            <button class="b_buy">Comprar</button>
            <button class="b_vista">Vista</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" />
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <h3>$101</h3>
          <div class="buy_buttons">
            <button class="b_buy">Comprar</button>
            <button class="b_vista">Vista</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/2.jpg" />
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <h3>$101</h3>
          <div class="buy_buttons">
            <button class="b_buy">Comprar</button>
            <button class="b_vista">Vista</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

(I removed unnecesary code)

Comment: I edited to use a snippet - notice how it may change your question as flex on narrow screens will "flex" to stack them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this with media-queries. I wrote a skeleton for you which you can use. Hope it helps!?

```css
.w {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap:2px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.w > div {
  margin-bottom:2px;
  background: gray;
  width: 24%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  .w {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  .w > div {
    margin-bottom:2px;
    background: gray;
    width: 33%;
  }  
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .w {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  .w > div {
    margin-bottom:2px;
    background: gray;
    width: 49%;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  
  <div>2</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>2</div>
  
  <div>3</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>3</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now the first row has 3 elements and then 1 item, 1 item, 1 item ... (each row)
edit: i can't modify the margins neither.

Comment: @LautaroRojas I though that you desire 3 items in each row?

Comment: Yes, but now the first row has 3 items. But then the second one has just one, and the third one has just one 
Like: 3 1 1 1 1

Comment: @LautaroRojas Are you checked the example right now? 3,3,2 . Sum 8 items.

Comment: I think I didn explain well.
This is what I want:
When fullscreen: 4 items in each row
When 1500px width: 3 items in each row
When 1100px width: 2 items in each row

In order to do this, I'm trying to remove the unused space to specify the margin I want between each item.

Comment: @LautaroRojas ok. Now i understand :-)

Comment: Thank you so much.
It's working perfectly when having 4 items and 2 items. But not when having 3.


https://imgur.com/a/zENJRQz

Tried using margin 0 but same results.

Comment: I tried removing rows.
When i use margin 0 with the items this happens:
https://imgur.com/a/j8OemKQ

Comment: @LautaroRojas Im really sorry. I could not understand what you meaning!? The example above works for you? If it works on the example and dont work on your code if your remove the row divs then the problem could occurs from the style.

Answer (score 0):

The purple part isn't margin, it's just unused space between items due to your `justify-content`. If you want to remove space between items, just change the property to `justify-content:center`.

```css
.row{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.item{
  width:33.33%; 
}
.a{
    background-color:blue;
}
.b{
    background-color:red;
}
.c{
    background-color:green;
}
.d{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.e{
    background-color:purple;
}
.f{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="item a">a</div>
    <div class="item b">b</div>
    <div class="item c">c</div> 
    <div class="item d">d</div> 
    <div class="item e">e</div> 
    <div class="item f">f</div> 
</div>
```

You can also chose how many items you have by row you can add a new row or set width to your items

Comment: Thanks for answering
The justify-content:center is not working for me, I don't know why. The unused space is not being removed.